# Recognize empty space in shelves by tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow

I am new in machine learning, I use tensorflow object detection from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection ,
I use ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco and I create dataset of 100 images of Cooler
 I have trained a model to detect two bottle images kept in cooler,

here is the screenshots 
[image: imgCooler1]
[image: imgCooler2]

see at imgCooler1, 2nd row of cooler, there is some empty space, i want to recognize that empty space of Cooler, please suggest some solutions for this

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the second row of the cooler as in between the coordinates 0-200 of the y-axis, or the 2nd row that's shown (~200-600 on the y-axis)? Do you have training data labelling the empty space?

Comment: Hi Kathy Wu, thanks for the reply, basically I want to recognize empty space of each row of the cooler, I want to count the number of bottles can be occupied on empty space, please refer screenshot in the link below

https://i.imgur.com/Ni9Ylc0.jpg

Comment: That would be a very different problem to solve, and probably more difficult than object detection. The model may have to estimate the volume of the empty space based on a 2d image, and then predict the number of objects that can be stored there. You could try creating training data consisting of images and labels for the empty spaces, along with the correct number of bottles can occupy those spaces.